# NPOI C# SetCellValue() of bool type via variable as string

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I want to SetCellValue() of bool type via variable as string for example:

string parameter = "TRUE";

and now I want to SetCellValue(parameter)

What is the correct way to set the cell value as boolean type from the string value above?

Thansk very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bool.Parse(string value)`

```
string parameter = "TRUE";

SetCellValue(bool.Parse(parameter));
```